# Restricting the background color to an ovalbox

Tags: color, backgrounds, varwidth, fancybox

The snippet

```
\documentclass[png,convert={density=600}]{standalone}
\usepackage{times,fancybox,varwidth,color}
\pagecolor{cyan}
\cornersize{1}

\begin{document}
\ovalbox{\large Hello}
\end{document}
```

generates the png image

[image: Hello]

with the help of `pdflatex -shell-escape question`.

How do I make the background fill just the ovalbox (while the ovalbox appears with no boundary)?

Comment: If you are ok with using `tikz` package then you can use `\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [draw=none, fill=cyan, rounded corners=5pt] {\large Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: I was hoping to delay reading the tikz documentation even longer, but whatever works is fine. If you are ok with my marking your answer as the correct one, but then marking another if it turns out a solution without tikz is possible, please add an answer.

Comment: You also can use pstricks (and auto-pst-pdf if you do not want to go the way latex -> dvi -> dvipdf) with this line:\psframebox*[fillcolor=cyan, framearc=0.5]{\large Hello}

Comment: This is not as easy with [`fancybox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox) since the box is constructed using 4 straight rules (top/bottom + left/right) and four corners (upper left/right, lower left/right). There is no single structure to bound colour within. Graphics packages like [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) can manage this without problem though.

Comment: @Calaf: Yep, I can understand why one would want to postpone learning `tikz`, but if you are doing any serious drawings (or already know `pstricks`), resistance is futile :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `tcolorbox`?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[png,convert={density=600}]{standalone}
\usepackage{times,tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\myovalbox}{colback=cyan,boxrule=0pt,arc=5pt,
  boxsep=0pt,left=3pt,right=3pt,top=3pt,bottom=3pt}

\begin{document}
\myovalbox{\large Hello}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tikz` solution:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[png,convert={density=600}]{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill=cyan, rounded corners=5pt] {\large Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```