# colored and framed equation numbers

Tags: color, numbering, amsmath

How do I color the equation numbers as given in the below picture.
Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
A second-linear differential equation has the form
$$P(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+Q(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+R(x)y=G(x)\tag{(1)}$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\fcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand\customtag[1]{\tag*{\qquad\fcolorbox{orange}{Cornsilk}{\textcolor{orange}{\footnotesize\textbf{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
 A second-linear differential equation has the form
\begin{equation}
P(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+Q(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+R(x)y=G(x)\customtag{1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want the equation numbers to be inside a colored circle then what should i do?

Comment: @C.S. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156386/117125